# Harnack type Estimates for a p-Poisson equation with constant source term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $B=B_1(0)\subset \mathbb R^N$ and let $u\geq 0$ solve the PDE
$$
-\Delta_p u=1\,\,\mbox{in $B$}
$$

Let another function $f$ be such that 
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta_p f =1 \;\;\mbox{in $B$}\\ 
f=0 \;\;\mbox{on $\partial B$}
\end{cases}
$$

I wish to show that in $B_{1/2}=B_{1/2}(0)$, $u-f$ satify a Harnack type estimate : 
$$
\frac{1}{C}(u-f)(0)\leq (u-f)\leq C (u-f)(0)
$$
For some $C$, an scaling invariant constant depending only on the dimension.

PS: it shall lead to same kind of estimates on $u$ because $f$ can be found explicitly as $f(x)=c(1-|x|^{p/(p-1)})$, $c$ is adjusted so that $f$ satisfy the given PDE.

Answer (score 0):

Harnack holds for $p$-harmonic functions ($\Delta_p u = 0$), but here $u-f$ is not $p$-harmonic since $\Delta_p$ is not linear. What you ask is related (maybe implies?) a strong comparison principle for the $p$-Laplace equation, which is an open problem for $N\geq 3$. A good reference for this is the notes on the $p$-Laplacian by Peter Lindqvist, which you can find on google.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, by strong comparision principle, do we mean $-\Delta_p u \leq -\Delta _p v \Rightarrow u \leq v$ provided $u-v=0 $ on $\partial B$? I think I have proof for $u \leq v $ a.e. But I fail to figure out how it help us to get the result.

Comment: That would be a weak comparison principle. Strong comparison principle would say that in addition, if $u(x)=v(x)$ for some $x$ in your domain, then $u\equiv v$.

Comment: The weak comparison principle definitely holds, and is a classical result.